# Solve an issue about init a single value not multiple value on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

How can I solve about initialization a single value? My log shows that I have an init two value together. but, I want only one value. Here's my code:

on my viewpagerAdapter who use an FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
ArrayList<Fragment> getData = new ArrayList<>();

public void getItem(int position)
{
    return getData.get(position);
}
```

and my fragment who use an viewpageradapter

```
viewpageradapter  = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tab.getTabCount())

viewpagerAdapter.addFragment(DataFragment.newInstance("1"),"Data 1");
viewpagerAdapter.addFragment(DataFragment.newInstance("2"),"Data 2");
ViewPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);
```

and my log say that in one times

```
I/datapassing:1
I/datapassing:2
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want ?

Comment: maybe, I want a value data is uploaded single value to be uploaded. for example, when I open the apps and then check in my logcat. value from datapassing show only one value and not 2 value at the same time

Comment: Please share complete code and also I am not able to understand your English

Comment: hello @aryanagarwal. now, i understand about my issue because i add value on onCreate(). because, it will be show a multiple value when init a viewpager. so that, i used onResume() on my fragment and it finish. thank you for help me